# Ошибка при установке kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Запускаю установку Kali Linux с флешки, при выборе пункта Install появляется черное окно, не на весь экран и ничего не происходит сколько бы не ждал. Устанавливаю Kali x86, у процессора архитектура x86, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: хммм Информативно..

Comment: опишите подробно условия проблеммы и быстро получите решение , проблем нет с устанвкой кали на любые современные системы

Answer (score 1):

из под винды флешку лучше писать программой RUFUS ,а если писали образ в линукс стандартной утилитой то видимо битый образ, если на винде писался образ нафлешку то руфус должен  исправит ситуацию

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй установить через Графическую установку, в Биос отключи безопасную загрузку(вроде так называется), если у тебя разделы дисков разные это не влияет на установку.У меня при установке был 1 диск с виндой и я его разделил в процессе установки.

Или через live режим попробуй, через загрузчик

Comment: Это уже в процессе установки

Answer (score -1):

Нужно привести файловую систему к должному виду перед установкой. У Windows и Linux разные файловые системы.

Comment: Так должна же запускаться установка, разве нет?

Comment: Вам сначала нужно пройтись акронисом или парагоном, отрезать кусочек от жесткого диска, для OC Linux рекомендуется выбрать родную систему Extfs, Ext2, Ext3, Ext4, ReiserFS, XFS.